# What are the building blocks of food called?

Tags: single-word-requests, food

What can the building block chemicals of food - like starch, pectin - be called?

I thought of "constituents" (my favourite) and "components" but is there a more specific or technically correct term?

> Did you know pectin can be used as a detergent for cleaning grease? The research introduces this and many other novel commercial applications for food _____ like starch, protease, and pectin.

Comment: There might be something better upon further reflection, but *potatoes have a starchy component* sounds much more natural to me. I don't think we *constituents* in food at all.

Comment: Indeed. @theonlygusti please read the [help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for this sort of question and ensure that all the information requested is provided. Thanks

Comment: @TinfoilHat "one of the components of potato is starch" sounds a bit weird to me

Comment: Can you add an example sentence with a fill-in-the-blank where the word would go?

Comment: @TinfoilHat done now

Comment: Food does NOT have building  blocks. Protease is NOT a nutrient. This question is scientifically flabby and the model sentence is nonsense. The answers from non-scientists are equally unsatisfactory. I'd advise deleting and reposting on SE Biology if you want to educate yourself in this area.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question and recommending the poster post on a site such as SE Biology where a scientifically sound answer is more likely to emerge.

Comment: @David is this a more correct description of the question I am trying to ask: what can the chemicals and groups of chemicals commonly found in and associated with food collectively be called?

Comment: Not that I see the issue with summing those up as building blocks as I did originally. Surely they are building blocks because the food item would not exist without them.

Comment: It seems to me that the idea you are trying to convey is that plants and substances derived from them and from animals that we may primary think of as food can be used for other things. This is highly unoriginal — think of the use of animal fat for lubrication, the use of vegetable oil for illumination, starch for stiffening collars (even the modern distillation of edible plants to ethanol). If you want to say something about pectin, just say it, and remember that most people won't even know what pectin is. "Pectin, which most people will associate with...is also used for removing grease.

Comment: @David the quote block in the sentence shows one example of what a "novel commercial applications for food _____" could be, and some examples of what "food _____"s should accommodate.

Comment: Constituents is appropriate. A quick look at dictionaries will justify this use.  As the answer is within the question but is neither discussed nor justified within it, I vote to close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because “Constituents” is appropriate. A quick look at dictionaries will justify this use.  As the answer is within the question but is neither discussed nor justified within it, I vote to close.

Comment: @TinfoilHat both are great, just what I was looking for. Compound is what I'll choose to use, thanks!

Comment: @theonlygusti — Your question was closed, so I couldn't provide insight anywhere but in the comments. When your question was reopened, my comment was apparently removed by a heavy-handed moderator. I might try to resurrect the comment as an answer, for posterity.

Comment: And the building blocks of chicken are . . .?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest **nutrients**, although this might be a little loose:

> Nutrient Classifications ...
>
> There are more than 40 different kinds of nutrients in food and they
> can generally be classified into the following 7 major groups:
>
> - Carbohydrates
> - Proteins
> - Fats
> - Vitamins
> - Minerals
> - Dietary fibre
> - Water

[[Hong Kong Dept of Health Centre for Health Protection](https://www.chp.gov.hk/en/static/100022.html)]

Comment: Enzymes, pectin can be classified as nutrients? Gluten?

Comment: "Honk" if you think fibre and water are nutrients. (Just so we know you never did biology).

Comment: @David Honk! Why not?

Comment: @theonlygusti — Mr Kong might not like it.

Answer (score 0):

In cooking they’re called *ingredients.*

Comment: Aren't ingredients the building blocks of meals/dishes? I think the question seems to be more about the chemical building blocks, and I wouldn't use the word 'ingredient' to describe that aspect. But I may have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @Heartspring I agree with you, but it's also true that most of the chemical building blocks of food can be individual cooking ingredients too (e.g. lots of acids, sweeteners, starch itself)

Answer (score -3):

I think the term you are looking for is: **[Emulsifier](https://www.britannica.com/science/emulsifier)**

> emulsifier, in foods, any of numerous chemical additives that encourage the suspension of one liquid in another, as in the mixture of oil and water in margarine, shortening, ice cream, and salad dressing. A number of emulsifiers are derived from algae, among them algin, carrageenan, and agar. Lecithins, such as those found in egg yolk, are also used as emulsifying agents.[...]